# Example of subgroup $H$ with the property $g H g^{-1}$ is properly contained in $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

After learning the definition of normal subgroup,
I would like to find an example of a group $G$ which has a subgroup $H$ such that there exists an element $g \in G$ such that $gHg^{-1} \subsetneq H$, namely, $gHg^{-1}$ is a proper subgroup of $H$.

Can anyone provide an example? Thank you very much!

Comment: See Example 1.33 [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GTe6.pdf).

Comment: @Peter the author is referring to strict containment

Comment: @basket thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks! Great example 1.33! I think you can put it to the answer, so that I can accept it. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I have posted my answer below.

Comment: This must be a candidate for the most frequently asked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Example 1.33 in [J.S. Milne's lecture notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GTe6.pdf).

Comment: Links die, so it is useful to accompany a link with something about what it contains - for example, here just give the example without proof!

Comment: @user1729:  You are right. However, I have to say that (IMHO) those notes are among the most longeve links in all mathematical Internet (they started in the '90s). Anyway, I'll try to rewrite the example here or to write a stabler reference if time allows me.